# When trying to activate XML package, RStudio throws error about R version

Tags: r, xml

I'm trying to activate XML in RStudio, but every time I do I get the error:

`Error: This is R 3.5.2, package ‘XML’ needs >= 4.0.0`

I feel like I need to update R, but I can't figure out how to do this. I've tried various things but nothing has worked.

I'm on a Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://uvastatlab.github.io/phdplus/installR.html

got me to the answer

> Go to https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/macosx/
> Click the link “R-3.5.2.pkg”
> When the file finishes downloading, double-click to install. You should be able to click “Next” to all dialogs to finish the installation.

But with R-4.0.2